# Error:Invalid use of argument matchers! 0 matchers expected, 1 recorded

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm Trying to do test case for my method, but I'm getting below error

> Invalid use of argument matchers! 0 matchers expected, 1 recorded

I don't know where the problem. I tried many things like (anyIny(), anyString()) also not work.

How I can handle the JsonObject?

The error in this line:  verify(mockPreparedStmnt, times(8)).setString(anyInt(), mock.toString());

Also I have another question:

How I can Handle if statement, if its not equal "ADD" in my case ?

This is the method I try to test it.

```
    public ApprovalManagementBean insertOrUpdateApprovalManagement(String body,
                                                                       String transactionType) throws IOException,
                                                                                                      JsonParseException,
                                                                                                      JsonMappingException {
            ApprovalManagementBean obj = new ApprovalManagementBean();
            List<JSONObject> beanList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(body);
            JSONObject jsonObjInput;
            String body2 = "";

            try {
                if (transactionType.equals("ADD")) {
                    int transactionNum = 23;
                    connection = getConnection();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        jsonObjInput = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String query =
                            "INSERT INTO  " + " " + getSchema_Name() + ".XXX_APROVAL_MANAGEMENT(EIT_CODE,TRANSACTION_NUM)\n" +
                            "VALUES(?,?)";
                        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                        ps.setString(1, jsonObjInput.get("eitCode").toString());
                        ps.setInt(2, transactionNum);
                        ps.executeUpdate();
                    }

                } else if (transactionType.equals("EDIT")) {
                    connection = getConnection();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        jsonObjInput = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String query =
                            "UPDATE  " + " " + getSchema_Name() + ".XXX_APROVAL_MANAGEMENT AM SET am.enable = ?";
                        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                        ps.setString(1,
                                     !jsonObjInput.isNull("enable") ? jsonObjInput.get("enable").toString() :"");
                        ps.executeUpdate();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //("Error: ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                closeResources(connection, ps, rs);
            }
            return obj;
        }



    public int getTransactionApprovalManagementNumber() {
        connection = getConnection();
        String query =
            "SELECT NVL(MAX(TRANSACTION_NUM),0) AS max_transaction_approval FROM  " +
            " " + getSchema_Name() + ".XXX_APROVAL_MANAGEMENT";
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                max_transaction = rs.getInt("max_transaction_approval");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //("Error: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeResources(connection, ps, rs);
        }

        max_transaction++;

        return max_transaction;

    }



        @Before
    public void setUp() throws SQLException {
        approvalManagementDAO = new ApprovalManagementDAO();
        when(mockConn.prepareStatement(anyString())).thenReturn(mockPreparedStmnt);
        doNothing().when(mockConn).commit();
        doNothing().when(mockPreparedStmnt).setString(anyInt(), anyString());
        when(mockPreparedStmnt.executeQuery()).thenReturn(mockResultSet);
        when(mockResultSet.next()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE);
        approvalManagementDAO = new ApprovalManagementDAO() {
                @Override
                public Connection getConnection() {
                    return mockConn;
                }
            };
    }

        @Test
    public void insertOrUpdateApprovalManagement() throws IOException,
                                                          JsonParseException,
                                                          JsonMappingException,
                                                          SQLException {
        String body = "[]";
        String transactionType = "ADD";
    JSONObject mock = Mockito.mock(JSONObject.class);
        approvalManagementDAO.insertOrUpdateApprovalManagement(body,
                                                               transactionType);
        verify(mockConn, times(1)).prepareStatement(anyString());

        verify(mockPreparedStmnt, times(8)).setString(anyInt(), mock.toString());
        //        verify(mockPreparedStmnt, times(1)).setInt(anyInt(), anyInt());
        verify(mockPreparedStmnt, times(1)).executeUpdate();

    }
```

Comment: Can you fix the example so that the `insertOrUpdateApprovalManagement` has at least the correct number of closing brackets? mock.toString() will only return null, as you haven`t declared anything else, but you are supposed to use matchers at this point anyway (either all matchers or none). You said you tried it, but you should get a different error in that case. The doNothing() mocks are not required as that is the default behaviour anyway.

Comment: Please check the updated. @second

Comment: Its still to much missing to just reproduce it myself. Can you reduce it to an [mre]? I guess one ps.setString per Branch should be enough, as well as adding the missing fields/methods of the ApprovalManagementDAO.

Comment: For the JSONArray: You could provide it as input parameter instead of body, so that you can mock it. Else you need to provide a valid body that contains the necesarry informations for your test. For the TransactionType: I am not sure what you want to express? Your tests should cover both branches.

Comment: Can You check it now please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your original class I stripped away some things.

---

Edit:
(I'll have yet to compare it with your 2nd edit, so it might not be want you had in mind)

Looks similiar enough to your 2nd edit, but you have to do something more to mock the behavious of the getTransactionApprovalManagementNumber() in the real case. Fow now you replaced it with a fixed number.

---

Take a look at this (I used JUnit 5 & Mockito 2.27.x):

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class Test {

    public static class ApprovalManagementDAO {

        public ApprovalManagementBean insertOrUpdateApprovalManagement(JSONArray arr, String transactionType)
                throws Exception {

            ApprovalManagementBean obj = new ApprovalManagementBean();
            JSONObject jsonObjInput;

            Connection connection = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            try {
                if (transactionType.equals("ADD")) {

                    connection = getConnectionFromAppsPro();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        jsonObjInput = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                        String query = "some insert query";
                        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);

                        ps.setString(1, jsonObjInput.get("eitCode").toString());
                        ps.setString(2, !jsonObjInput.isNull("segementName") ? jsonObjInput.get("segementName").toString() : "");

                        ps.executeUpdate();

                    }

                } else if (transactionType.equals("EDIT")) {
                    connection = getConnectionFromAppsPro();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        jsonObjInput = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String query = "some update query";
                        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                        ps.setString(1, !jsonObjInput.isNull("enable") ? jsonObjInput.get("enable").toString() : "");

                        ps.executeUpdate();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                closeResources(connection, ps, rs);
            }

            return obj;
        }

        private void closeResources(Connection connection, PreparedStatement ps, ResultSet rs) {
        }

        Connection getConnectionFromAppsPro() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    Connection mockConn;
    PreparedStatement mockPreparedStmnt;
    ApprovalManagementDAO approvalManagementDAO;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws SQLException {

        mockConn = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
        mockPreparedStmnt = Mockito.mock(PreparedStatement.class);

        Mockito.when(mockConn.prepareStatement(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockPreparedStmnt);

        approvalManagementDAO = new ApprovalManagementDAO() {

            @Override
            public Connection getConnectionFromAppsPro() {
                return mockConn;
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void insertOrUpdateApprovalManagement() throws Exception {

        String transactionType = "ADD";

        JSONObject mockJsonObject = Mockito.mock(JSONObject.class);
        Mockito.when(mockJsonObject.get(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("");

        JSONArray mockJsonArray = Mockito.mock(JSONArray.class);
        Mockito.when(mockJsonArray.length()).thenReturn(1);
        Mockito.when(mockJsonArray.getJSONObject(0)).thenReturn(mockJsonObject);

        approvalManagementDAO.insertOrUpdateApprovalManagement(mockJsonArray, transactionType);
        Mockito.verify(mockConn, Mockito.times(1)).prepareStatement(Mockito.anyString());

        Mockito.verify(mockPreparedStmnt, Mockito.times(2)).setString(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString());
        Mockito.verify(mockPreparedStmnt, Mockito.times(1)).executeUpdate();

    }
}
```

---

In case you do not want to change the method signature remember to use a valid json format in the body, for example: `[{"eitCode": "x", "segementName": "y"}]`

Comment: It give me this error 
org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Comment: That shouldnt come from my code. I don`t create a real JSONArray object anyway. Can you update your question with what you have done? Or we can use a chatroom?